Determining initial algebras and final coalgebras for a given functor without using limits/colimits
I'm trying to find the final coalgebra for a certain functor but I have no idea how to do that in general, so I was hoping to go through the process with some simpler examples. In section 4.1, The Method of Coalgebra gives one example of an initial algebra:

For the functor $N$: Set $\to$ Set mapping $X$ to $1+X$ and $f:X \to Y$
to $1+f$, the initial algebra is ($\mathbb{N}$, [zero, succ]) where
zero($*$)=0 and succ($n$)=$n+1$.

and one example of a final coalgebra:

For the functor Str: Set $\to$ Set mapping $X$ to $\mathbb{N}\times X$
and $f: X \to Y$ to $1_\mathbb{N}\times f$, the final coalgebra is
$(\mathbb{N}^\omega,\langle$head, tail$\rangle)$, where
$\mathbb{N}^\omega$ is the set of sequences of natural numbers, and
for such a sequence $\sigma$, head$(\sigma)=\sigma(0)$ and
tail$(\sigma)=(\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\dots)$.

I have drawn the diagrams and followed them around to determine that indeed, any arrow $f: \mathbb{N} \to X$ is fully defined by the algebra homomorphism square, and similarly, any arrow $f: X \to \mathbb{N}^\omega$ is fully defined by the coalgebra homomorphism square, making $\mathbb{N}$ initial and $\mathbb{N}^\omega$ final for their respective functors.
However, if I were just given the functors and asked to find the initial algebra / final coalgebra, I'm not sure how to do that. For the $N$-algebra, I assume $\alpha: 1+A \to A$ is initial and get

$$f(\alpha_1(*))=g_1(*)$$
$$f(\alpha_2(a))=g_2(f(a)) \quad \forall a \in A.$$
Clearly $f(\alpha_1(*))$ is fully defined for each $(X,[g_1,g_2])$. And I think if for some $a\in A$, $a=\alpha_1(*)$, the right $\alpha_2$ would yield an inductive definition of $f$ making $(A,[\alpha_1,\alpha_2])$ initial but I don't know how to prove that this is the only way $f$ exists and is unique for every $N$-algebra, or how this means $A=\mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha=$[zero, succ].
Similarly for the Str-coalgebra, assuming $\beta: B \to \mathbb{N}\times B$ is final, I get that $\forall x \in X$:

$$\beta_1(f(x))=g_1(x)$$
$$\beta_2(f(x))=f(g_2(x)).$$
And again $\beta_1(f(x))$ is fully determined, but I can't get any further than that. Any help would be much appreciated.
